# CopyPicture method of range class failed - sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, charts, copy-paste

I have a VBA code which I am using to copy ranges as a picture and paste them into a chart. It does this so I can save it into a picture. This code has like a 70% success rate, and when it doesn't work, it gives out the error "CopyPicture method of range class failed". I don't understand why it can sometimes work and sometimes doesn't given that it is taking the same inputs.

Can anyone help?

```
Public Sub ExportRange(workbookPath As String, sheetName As String, rangeString As String, savepath As String)

    Set tempWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(workbookPath)

    Dim selectRange As range
    Set selectRange = Worksheets(sheetName).range(rangeString)
    Dim numRows As Long
    numRows = selectRange.Rows.Count
    Dim numCols As Long
    numCols = selectRange.Columns.Count

    ' Transfer selection to a new sheet and autofit the columns
    selectRange.Copy
    Dim tempSheet As Worksheet
    Set tempSheet = Sheets.Add
    tempSheet.range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Set selectRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    selectRange.Select
    selectRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

    Dim tempSheet2 As Worksheet
    Set tempSheet2 = Sheets.Add
    Dim oChtobj As Excel.ChartObject
    Set oChtobj = tempSheet2.ChartObjects.Add( _
        selectRange.Left, selectRange.Top, selectRange.Width, selectRange.Height)

    Dim oCht As Excel.Chart
    Set oCht = oChtobj.Chart
    oCht.Paste
    oCht.Export filename:=savepath
    oChtobj.Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempSheet.Delete
    tempSheet2.Delete
    tempWorkBook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it fail for the same image / worksheet, etc? or in different cases? As in if you run a loop executing this 100 times, does it run 0 times for some cases and 100 times for others or does it run some number in between and then stop with the error?

Comment: It fails for the same image and worksheet. I run this Sub in a loop with 6 images, and when it fails, it can fail on any one of the images, not necessarily always the same one.

Comment: Try enclosing your main code logic within `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: Just tried it, same problem. Sometimes it work sometimes not. And when it doesn't it doesn't stop on the same part of the loop of 6 images every time.

Comment: I replaced the workbook that I copy the ranges from with a blank sheet and it produces the error as well, perhaps even more often so. Could it be that the code is running so fast that some parts of it is not waiting for the previous code to finish?

Comment: ohhh... in that case try running the code in debug mode. put enough breakpoints, and slowly cycle through it. See if it fails now. if it doesn't then you've solved the problem

Comment: insert Application.DoEvents or simply `DoEvents` where you would like a bit of slowdown and see what happens.

Comment: Had the same problem some times that I (king of?) solved by catching the error and resuming the execution on the same line.

Comment: Had same problem when invoking CopyAsPicture through win32com (from python). Ugly workaround: 10 retries..

Comment: Anybody looking for solution, use this before paste: `.ChartArea.Parent.Select`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53844969/427969

Comment: @VincentG, I'm a bit of a novice - how do you resume execution on the same line?

Comment: From inside an error handler, `Resume` will resume execution from the line that generated the error, `Resume Next` will resume execution from the next line. `Resume someplace` will resume execution from the `someplace:` label.

Answer (score 4):

i have found a way to force excel to wait until the clipboard has a picture in it, because sometimes it's too fast:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 

'just after copypicture, add this: (in my case i added it inside pastepicture, or i'd have too much coding )
Dim T#
  Do
      Waiting (2)
Loop Until IsClipboardFormatAvailable(2) Or Timer - T > 0.3

Sub Waiting(ByVal Mili_Seconds&)
Sleep Mili_Seconds
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! in my case "applicaiton.displayalert = false" was the problem !

Comment: This does not work always! Especially in Excel 2016.

Comment: edited the answer ans simplified it.
This final solution works ALWAYS

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the very same issue than you and I think is nothing to do with our VBA code or lack of programming skills. The error it's too random.

Moreover, if after getting the error message I clicked DEBUG and pressed <kbd>F8</kbd> to continue executing the code step by step, then I was able to skip the error. After the problematic line I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> to continue in normal execute mode.

Of course, the above is not a solution but reveals nothing wrong with my coding.

Well, I did this and it worked for me:

before this sentence,

```
rgToPic.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
```

I added this one:

```
rgToPic.Copy  'just for nothing
```

and I never have had the error in `CopyPicture` method again.

---

Looking for this issue in other places I found out some users were able to skip the error by introducing this sentence before the `CopyPicture` method:

```
    application.CutCopyMode=false
```

Comment: That was the solution for me.Just debugging the code worked.I had to hit F8 all the way!

Comment: 'Application.CutCopyMode=false' worked well for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. My own solution was to add a 800 ms `WAIT` time before the `.CopyPicture` command (600 ms didn't work). Then, I found this page. I have tried every method on this page to no avail until this one - adding a `.Copy` command before `.CopyPicture`. I still need a wait time but it's now 50 ms.

Comment: That was also the solution for me. After spending almost 1 day, finally I found this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was to add a delay BEFORE the CopyPicture method.   We are tweaking it shorter as I type this, but I know a 50 ms delay was working fine:

> Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
>
> 'Set Range you want to capture
>
> Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = Range("B2:D6")
>
> Sleep (50) ' Pause in milliseconds to prevent runtime error on CopyPicture, your system may be able to use shorter sleep, or may need longer...
>
> ' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
>
> rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

Comment: Indeed. This is a timing runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, maybe this will help someone.
I was struggling with similar problem for a long time. `CopyPicture` failed
(on some computers more often than others, but hard to replicate on my laptop) when I was copying the range that
contained an embedded PNG picture. It only failed in `Application.Visible=0` mode, `Application.Visible=1` worked fine (for my application it is mandatory to run Excel in invisible mode). Finally I found that I can reproduce the problem 100% of the times when run on a VM with 1 CPU. The following solution is weird, but seems to be solving my problem completely.

Embedded PNG is a `Shape` in Excel API terms. I just needed to cycle through the shapes (not even doing anything) before calling `CopyPicture`:

```py
# 'rng' is a range that I want CopyPicture on 
for shape in rng.Shapes: pass
rng.CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlBitmap)
```

My finding is somewhat similar to [this solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/cannot-use-the-rangecopypicture-method-to-copy-the/8bb3ef11-51c0-4fb1-9a8b-0d062bde582b?auth=1),
where `CopyPicture` was failing on a range with charts. In their case,
activating workbook and range itself helped.

Hypothesizing, it seems plausible that on a slow or heavily loaded computer Excel does "lazy processing" of the complex objects on a page, i.e. not rendering them until object is accessed in some way. One way to force rendering seems to run in `Visible=1` mode. Another way is to cycle through the objects. If this is the case, then it is a bug of Excel's `CopyPicture` implementation where it doesn't force complex objects to render before trying to copy. When copy method finds out rendering for the target range is not ready, it simply throws an error instead of forcing the range to render. Well, at least that's my theory.

Answer (score 1):

My work around for this was to throw it in an error catching while loop and keep retrying it until it was able to fully copy the range without an error message. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, was clearing the clipboard before I copied the picture with `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Best practice I imagine is to paste what you need, and directly afterwards clear the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had similar problem and I could solve it by changing between `xlScreen` and `xlPrinter` in `selectRange.CopyPicture`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The `CopyPicture` method sends the result to clipboard. But due to security reason, Win10 forbids access to clipboard while screen is locked. Therefore if you run the macro while locking screen, the `CopyPicture` method will fail with error code 1004.
The same error happens with `Worksheet.Pictures.Paste`.

On the other hand, simple `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` won't pop error. When the clipboard is not accessible, the content won't be copied to clipboard but VBA won't complain about it.

Unfortunately, `PasteSpecial` doesn't have the option to paste as picture.
The only simple workaround is leaving your computer unlocked while running the macro.

Comment: Your information doesn't seem to account for the following from the original poster: "This code has like a 70% success rate".

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the solutions above still didn't fix the issue for me I kept searching and finally ChatGPT helped me build the following code after asking it to use TRY / CATCH in vba:

```
..
                Dim retryCount As Integer
                retryCount = 0
retry_CopyPicture:
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                oRng.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
                GoTo ContinueExecution
            
ErrorHandler:
                retryCount = retryCount + 1
                If retryCount <= 10 Then
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                    Resume retry_CopyPicture
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error while trying to copy the picture 10 times. Macro Aborts."
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            
ContinueExecution:
...
```

Since using this approach I count every once in a while a retryCount of 1 or 2. The code now works flawlessly.

Comment: You just captured the possible issue not solve them. Just rember to figure what is going wrong should be the first principle.

Answer (score -4):

I found a easy way to fix this issue with which I was struggling for a few months. I know this is a "BAD CODE" but it helped and worked perfect for me. In my case details were getting copied but the debug error window was populating. Hence I just skipped the debug window and my life became easier.

Fix is just add below code in front of the "copy" code in your VBA. This will sure fix this error.

```
On Error Resume Next
```