# Paste method of Chart object not working as expected in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a code, recently updated to Excel 2016 that has shown some strange malfunctions. After quite a lot of debugging, I found that one of the errors were caused by Excel failing to handle a image correctly.

The code below has a simple purpose, to copy a used part of a worksheet to an image, and then insert that image as a comment in a worksheet.

However, in order for the function to work properly in Excel 2016, I need to repeat the paste operation several times as you can see in the code.

The workaround is functional, but I believe that some degree of understanding of why is needed, and I would also prefer a more clean solution.

```
Public Sub CopySheetToComment(ReferenceSheet As Worksheet, Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim Sh As Shape

Dim pWidth As Single
Dim PHeight As Single
Dim cmt As Comment

Dim TempPicFile As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Path temporary file
TempPicFile = Environ("temp") & "\img.png"

' Define and copy relevant area
Set rng = ReferenceSheet.UsedRange
rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

pWidth = rng.Width
PHeight = rng.Height

' Paste copied image to chart and then export to file
Dim C As Object
Set C = ReferenceSheet.Parent.Charts.add
Dim Ch As ChartObject
Set Ch = C.ChartObjects.add(Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height)

' Ugly solution that is working in Excel 2016....
Ch.Chart.Paste
DoEvents
Ch.Chart.Paste
DoEvents
Ch.Chart.Paste
Ch.Chart.Export TempPicFile


' Remove chart object
Dim Alerts As Boolean
Alerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
C.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = Alerts

' Remove old comment
On Error Resume Next
Target.Comment.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
' Add comment
Set cmt = Target.AddComment
Target.Comment.Visible = True

' Infoga bild till kommentar
With cmt.Shape
    .Fill.UserPicture TempPicFile
    .Width = pWidth * 1.33333
    .Height = PHeight * 1.33333
End With
'Target.Comment.visible = False

End Sub
```

And to call it, this example works:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("blad2")
CopySheetToComment ws, Range("D8")

End Sub
```

Theories on why this works but not DoEvents, or suggestions for proper code is requested.

Comment: [Stephen Bullen's Excel Page](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/excel/) PastePicture function creates an image file from the clipboard without using the charts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into similar problems after updating my Excel version. This is how I solved it:

```
Dim pChart As Chart    'will serve as a temporary container for your pic

rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture    'using the rng you use in your code here
Set pChrt = Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear
With pChrt
    .ChartArea.Parent.Select    'new for Excel 2016
    .Paste
    .Export Filename:=TempPicFile, Filtername:="PNG"    'TempPicFile is what you defined in your code, so path + file name
    .Delete
End With
```

You can then use the PNG and paste it as you do, asigning a width/height to it.
Additionally, I would set `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`at the beginning of a sub and set it back to `True`just at the end - quicker and less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Also works with:

Dim Ch As ChartObject

'adding

Ch.Chart.Parent.Select

'then

Ch.Chart.Paste

'because Microsoft....

Comment: Please try to edit your answer and be more clear on what you are explaining using examples and sharing links to the documentation if proceeds.