# Save pictures by VBA on Windows 10 lock screen

Tags: excel, vba

i have a vba code that saves a range of cells in image format; however, if the PC has a locked screen, the images that are saved are all white:

```
Range("B6:M80").Select
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
GifLargh = Selection.Width
GifAlt = Selection.Height
Sheets("Summary").Select
Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ch = Sheets("Summary").ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, GifLargh, GifAlt)
Sheets("Summary").ChartObjects(1).Activate
Worksheets("Summary").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Select
Worksheets("Summary").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Paste
Worksheets("Summary").ChartObjects(1) _
.Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Macro\Summary.gif", FilterName:="GIF"
```

the same code works perfectly if the screen is not locked: does anyone have a suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). It might be that `Selection` is not what you expect it to be. Get rid of all `.Select` and `Selection.` statements, then [edit] your question and add your new code.

Comment: Also see here: [VBA CopyPicture fails on locked screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791292/vba-copypicture-fails-on-locked-screen-error-1004-cannot-empy-clipboard) • Did you get any error message?

Comment: Thank you @PEH, I try to answer in order:
- I have read the guide but I am quite new on VBA and I have not understood how to modify avoiding to use select in this specific case.
- What do you mean by "It might be that Selection is not what you expect it to be"?
- No, I'm not getting any error messages, simply instead of saving the contents of the cells in the image, save a completely white image.

thanks for your patience and support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use `.Select` or `.Activate` or `Selection` unless you really need to. This makes your code unreliable and extremley slow.

   So instead of

   ```
   Range("B6:M80").Select
   Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
   ```

   write it without

   ```
   Range("B6:M80").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
   ```
2. Make sure all your `Range`, `Cells`, `Columns` and `Rows` objects have a worksheet specified. Otherwise Excel cannot know for sure in which worksheet the range `Range("B6:M80")` is.
   So specify a worksheet like below:

   ```
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B6:M80")
   ```
3. There is a difference between `Sheets` and `Worksheets`. While `Worksheets` only contains worksheets, `Sheets` also contains chart sheets or others. So don't use them mixed. If you mean worksheet then don't use `Sheet` for that.
4. Declare all your variables properly before using them. Make sure you use `Option Explicit`.

---

So if you clean it up it would look something like this

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your source worksheet") '‹~~ adjust your sheet name

wsSource.Range("B6:M80").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

Dim GifLargh As Double
GifLargh = wsSource.Range("B6:M80").Width

Dim GifAlt As Double
GifAlt = wsSource.Range("B6:M80").Height

Dim wsSum As Worksheet
Set wsSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ch = wsSum .ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, GifLargh, GifAlt)

With wsSum.ChartObjects(1)
    .Activate      '‹~~ might not be necessary (check it)
    .Chart.Select  '‹~~ might not be necessary (check it)
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Macro\Summary.gif", FilterName:="GIF"
End With
```

If this code produces white images too, then there might be the probability that you cannot screenshot with `.CopyPicture` if the screen is locked.

Comment: This code works perfectly (changing `.Chart.Select` with `.Select`) if the screen is not locked.
If it is blocked, you have the same error (runtime 1004 executing `.CopyPicture`) indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791292/vba-copypicture-fails-on-locked-screen-error-1004-cannot-empy-clipboard. Thanks anyway for the support!

Comment: @Alessandro yes, that is what I assumed to happen. So it looks like it is not possible because you cannot take a screenshot of a screen that is paused.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using a Keboard and Mouse blocker like this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/winkeylock/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue running macros from Task Scheduler. I don't have a solution as yet.

However, in terms of preventing your screen from locking you can just issue a VBA.SendKeys "+" to send the shift key alone.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30698847)