# How can I solve this VBA error - 'Runtimeerror1004: CopyPicture Method of Range Class Failed'?

Tags: python, excel, vba, automation

I know people have asked this question before but I can't find a straightforward answer on how to fix this. I'm trying to automate the process of taking screenshots of some of my sheets within a defined range and sending them to my email. I keep getting this error on one of my lines in the code ('strRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture'). Can someone please help me with a solution to this?

```
Sub range_to_image(shtname, FileName As String)
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
Sheets(shtname).Activate
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Dim strRng As Range
Set strRng = Range(Range("start"), Range("end"))
Application.CutCopyMode = False
strRng.Copy
strRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = strRng.Width
lHeight = strRng.Height

Set Cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)
Cht.Activate
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
With Cht.Chart
  .Paste
  .Export FileName:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pictures\" & FileName & "-" & shtname & 
".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
End With

Cht.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the actual error you get?

Answer (score 1):

[CopyPicture method of range class failed - sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740062/copypicture-method-of-range-class-failed-sometimes)

The answer is here.